# CSS elements stacking, ontop error

Tags: html, css

I have no idea why my buttons are stacking on top of each other, I set a height and gave margins but their still ontop of each other. I don't want to use display:block; because that gives them a full width and I don't want to define the width because I want the buttons to change width depending on the word count.

```
<a class="btn blue-btn" href="#">Button</a>

.blue-btn{
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
-moz-background-clip: padding;
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;
background-color: #1b93b7;
}

.btn{
    height:30px;
    padding:13px 35px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    margin:10px 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3L4vB/

Comment: a element is inline element so you have to add display:inline-block to your .btn class

Comment: @ArdaChapuler Add that as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a element is inline element so you have to add display:inline-block to your .btn class

Comment: A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3L4vB/2/) to support your answer, i also removed background-clip off the hover state as it's unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you I through inline-block was for displaying an element as a block but the inline assigned it a float property too I guess that's not the case then?

Comment: Actually its not float
--[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3L4vB/5/) with float
--[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3L4vB/6/) without float